# Creating one merged variable from multiple separate one

Tags: r, dataframe, recode, categorization

Any help would be greatly appreciated

I have a file exported from a PCR plate software. I have already coded the call for all alleles and have now merged them into one data frame.

I need to create a new variable merging the 3 alleles (G1-1, G1-2, and G2) to get a final genotype.

I then need to count the occurrence of the alleles to generate the other 3 APOL1 risk variables that I need to generate.

```
Allele logic for final genotype:

+/G2 = (G1-1-1(+) & G1-1-2(+)) & (G1-2-1(+) & G1-2-2(+)) & (occurence of (G2) at either G2-1 or G2-2)

+/+ = (G1-1-1(+) & G1-1-2(+)) & (G1-2-1(+) & G1-2-2(+)) & (G2-1(+) & G2-2(+))

G2/G2 = (G1-1-1(+) & G1-1-2(+)) & (G1-2-1(+) & G1-2-2(+)) & (G2-1(G2) & G2-2(G2))

G1^GM/+ = (occurence of (G1^S342G) at either G1-1-1 or G1-1-2) & (occurence of (G1^I384M) at either G1-2-1 or G1-2-2) & (G2-1(+) & G2-2(+))

G1^G+/+ = (occurence of (G1^S342G) at either G1-1-1 or G1-1-2) & (G1-2-1(+) & G1-2-2(+)) & (G2-1(+) & G2-2(+))

G1^GM/G1^GM = (occurence of (G1^S342G) at both G1-1-1 or G1-1-2) & (occurence of (G1^I384M) at both G1-2-1 or G1-2-2) & (G2-1(+) & G2-2(+))

G1^GM/G2 = (occurence of (G1^S342G) at either G1-1-1 or G1-1-2) & (occurence of (G1^I384M) at either G1-2-1 or G1-2-2) & (occurence of (G2) at either G2-1 or G2-2)

G1^G+/G2 = (occurence of (G1^S342G) at either G1-1-1 or G1-1-2) & (G1-2-1(+) & G1-2-2(+) & (occurence of (G2) at either G2-1 or G2-2)
```

[Original dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dAKX.png)

[Final dataframe needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQNaI.png)

Original Dataframe structure

```
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   28 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ G1-1-1   : chr  "+" "+" "+" "+" ...
 $ G1-1-2   : chr  "+" "+" "+" "+" ...
 $ G1-2-1   : chr  "+" "+" "+" "+" ...
 $ G1-2-2   : chr  "+" "+" "+" "+" ...
 $ G2-1     : chr  "+" "+" "+" "+" ...
 $ G2-2     : chr  "G2" "+" "G2" "G2" ...
```

```
The APOL1 Risk variables logic is below:

If (+/+) categorize as 1 in "no APOL1 Risk Alleles"

If (+/G2) or (G1^GM/+) or (G1^G+/+) categorize as 1 in "1 APOL1 Risk Alleles"

If (G1^GM/G1^GM) or (G1^GM/G2) or (G2/G2) categorize as 1 in "2 APOL1 Risk Alleles"
```

Comment: Can you provide the logic behind the calculated fields?

Comment: @Ben I have added allele combinations

Comment: @NaremanDarwish I have added the logic behind the calculated fields, any insight would be greatly appreciated

Comment: @Ben I have been looking for a specialized R package, I will continue looking, thanks for your help

Comment: @Jordan in the logic it is mentioned G1-2-2 however there is no such column

Comment: @NaremanDarwish that was a typo in the structure provided. I have corrected accordingly

Comment: For Allele logic for final genotype what's the logic behind G1/G1GM also G1G+/+ in the expected output?

Comment: @NaremanDarwish the genotype of G1/G1GM isn't a possible genotype combination and I already listed the logic for G1G+/+

Comment: G1/G1GM exists in the final output image in row 8 https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQNaI.png

Comment: @NaremanDarwish Sorry for the confusion, that should be listed as G1GM/G1GM

Comment: Also row 22 G1G+/+ does not match the logic given instead it matches the logic of G1G/G2

Comment: For row 8 I think it matches G1GM/+ not G1GM/G1GM, can you please check this as well?

Comment: @NaremanDarwish I edited the allelic logic, the logic for G1G+/G2 was incorrect. Row 22 is G1G+/+. For row 8 it is G1GM/G1GM as the G1^S342G and G1^I384M occurs in both columns for G1-1 and G1-2. G1GM/+ would be the case if G1^S342G and G1^I384M only occurs in one of each.

Comment: Please check the answers, I have updated the logic accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement the logic easily using dplyr functions.

Implementing the logic given this should be the code needed to  do that logic;

```
library(dplyr)

data <-
  data.frame(
    G1_1_1 = c("+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "G1S342G", "+", "G1S342G", "+", "+", "+", "+",
               "G1S342G", "G1S342G", "+", "G1S342G", "+", "+", "+", "G1S342G", "+", "+",
               "G1S342G", "+", "G1S342G", "G1S342G"),
    G1_1_2 = c("+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "G1S342G", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+",
               "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+"),
    G1_2_1 = c("+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "G1I384M", "+", "G1I384M", "+", "+", "+", "+",
               "G1I384M", "G1I384M", "+", "G1I384M", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "G1I384M",
               "+", "G1I384M", "G1I384M"),
    G1_2_2 = c("+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "G1I384M", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+",
               "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+"),
    G2_1 = c("+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+",
             "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+"),
    G2_2 = c("G2", "+", "G2", "G2", "G2", "+", "+", "+", "G2", "G2", "+", "G2", "+", "G2", "G2",
             "+", "+", "+", "G2", "+", "G2", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+"),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )

result <-
  data %>% mutate(
    "Final genotype of APOL1" = 
      case_when(
        # +/+ = (G1-1-1(+) & G1-1-2(+)) & (G1-2-1(+) & G1-2-2(+)) & (G2-1(+) & G2-2(+))
        G1_1_1 == "+" & G1_1_2 == "+" & G1_2_1 == "+" & 
          G1_2_2 == "+" & G2_1 == "+" & G2_2 == "+" ~ "+/+",

        # G2/G2 = (G1-1-1(+) & G1-1-2(+)) & (G1-2-1(+) & G1-2-2(+)) & (G2-1(G2) & G2-2(G2))
        G1_1_1 == "+" & G1_1_2 == "+" & G1_2_1 == "+" & 
          G1_2_2 == "+" & G2_1 == "G2" & G2_2 == "G2" ~ "G2/G2",

        # G1^GM/G1^GM = (occurence of (G1^S342G) at both G1-1-1 or G1-1-2) 
        # & (occurence of (G1^I384M) at both G1-2-1 or G1-2-2) & (G2-1(+) & G2-2(+))
        G1_1_1 == "G1S342G" & G1_1_2 == "G1S342G" & G1_2_1 == "G1I384M" & 
          G1_2_2 == "G1I384M" & G2_1 == "+" & G2_2 == "+" ~ "G1GM/G1GM",

        #+/G2 = (G1-1-1(+) & G1-1-2(+)) & (G1-2-1(+) & G1-2-2(+)) 
        #& (occurence of (G2) at either G2-1 or G2-2)
        G1_1_1 == "+" & G1_1_2 == "+" & G1_2_1 == "+" & 
          G1_2_2 == "+" & (G2_1 == "G2" | G2_2 == "G2") ~ "+/G2",

        # G1^G+/+ = (occurence of (G1^S342G) at either G1-1-1 or G1-1-2) 
        # & (G1-2-1(+) & G1-2-2(+)) & (G2-1(+) & G2-2(+))
        (G1_1_1 == "G1S342G" | G1_1_2 == "G1S342G") & G1_2_1 == "+" & 
          G1_2_2 == "+" & G2_1 == "+" & G2_2 == "+" ~ "G1G+/+",

        # G1^G+/G2 = (occurence of (G1^S342G) at either G1-1-1 or G1-1-2) 
        # & (G1-2-1(+) & G1-2-2(+) & (occurence of (G2) at either G2-1 or G2-2)
        (G1_1_1 == "G1S342G" | G1_1_2 == "G1S342G") & G1_2_1 == "+" & 
          G1_2_2 == "+" & (G2_1 == "G2" | G2_2 == "G2") ~ "G1G+/G2",

        # G1^GM/+ = (occurence of (G1^S342G) at either G1-1-1 or G1-1-2) & 
        # (occurence of (G1^I384M) at either G1-2-1 or G1-2-2) & (G2-1(+) & G2-2(+))
        (G1_1_1 == "G1S342G" | G1_1_2 == "G1S342G") & 
          (G1_2_1 == "G1I384M" | G1_2_2 == "G1I384M") & 
          G2_1 == "+" & G2_2 == "+" ~ "G1GM/+",

        # G1^GM/G2 = (occurence of (G1^S342G) at either G1-1-1 or G1-1-2) & 
        # (occurence of (G1^I384M) at either G1-2-1 or G1-2-2) & 
        # (occurence of (G2) at either G2-1 or G2-2)
        (G1_1_1 == "G1S342G" | G1_1_2 == "G1S342G") & 
          (G1_2_1 == "G1I384M" | G1_2_2 == "G1I384M") & 
          (G2_1 == "G2" | G2_2 == "G2") ~ "G1GM/G2",

        TRUE ~ NA_character_),

    "no APOL1 Risk Alleles" = ifelse(`Final genotype of APOL1` == "+/+", 1, NA),

    "1 APOL1 Risk Alleles" = 
      ifelse(`Final genotype of APOL1` %in% c("+/G2", "G1GM/+", "G1G+/+"), 1, NA),

    "2 APOL1 Risk Alleles" =
      ifelse(`Final genotype of APOL1` %in% c("G1GM/G1GM", "G1GM/G2", "G2/G2"), 1, NA),
  )

glimpse(result)

# Observations: 28
# Variables: 10
# $ G1_1_1                    <chr> "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "G1S342G", "+", "G1S342G", ...
# $ G1_1_2                    <chr> "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "G1S342G", "+", "+", "+", "...
# $ G1_2_1                    <chr> "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "G1I384M", "+", "G1I384M", ...
# $ G1_2_2                    <chr> "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "G1I384M", "+", "+", "+", "...
# $ G2_1                      <chr> "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+...
# $ G2_2                      <chr> "G2", "+", "G2", "G2", "G2", "+", "+", "+", "G2", "G2", "+", "...
# $ `Final genotype of APOL1` <chr> "+/G2", "+/+", "+/G2", "+/G2", "+/G2", "+/+", "+/+", "G1GM/G1G...
# $ `no APOL1 Risk Alleles`   <dbl> NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, 1, ...
# $ `1 APOL1 Risk Alleles`    <dbl> 1, NA, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 1, NA, 1, NA, 1, NA, 1,...
# $ `2 APOL1 Risk Alleles`    <dbl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, N...
```

Comment: thank you again for your help this code worked great. I would really value your opinion/help for this problem I am having with the same data -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59980225/validation-check-using-controls-with-know-genotype