# Validation Check using controls with know genotype

Tags: r, dataframe, validation, dataset, data-manipulation

Please Help!!

I have the following dataframe (named Final_APOL1). I have a code that runs through Bio-Rad PCR output files to generate a final APOL1 genotype. Controls with known genotype are placed in wells E01, E02, F01, F02, G01, G02, H01, and H02. I have a separate dataframe (named Validation_controls) containing the known/correct genotypes that should be found in these well.

I need a code to validate and confirm that wells in both dataframes match and a way for this to be noted for the user using the final code.

Any Help would be appreciated

dataframe (Final_APOL1)

```
"A03", "A04", "A05", "A06", "A07", "A08", "A09", "A10", "A11", 
"A12", "B01", "B02", "B03", "B04", "B05", "B06", "B07", "B08", 
"B09", "B10", "B11", "B12", "C01", "C02", "C03", "C04", "C05", 
"C06", "C07", "C08", "C09", "C10", "C11", "C12", "D01", "D02", 
"D03", "D04", "D05", "D06", "D07", "D08", "D09", "D10", "D11", 
"D12", "E01", "E02", "E03", "E04", "E05", "E06", "E07", "E08", 
"E09", "E10", "E11", "E12", "F01", "F02", "F03", "F04", "F05", 
"F06", "F07", "F08", "F09", "F10", "F11", "F12", "G01", "G02", 
"G03", "G04", "G05", "G06", "G07", "G08", "G09", "G10", "G11", 
"G12", "H01", "H02", "H03", "H04", "H05", "H06", "H07", "H08", 
"H09", "H10", "H11", "H12"), class = "factor"), G1_1_1 = c("Blank", 
"Blank", "+", "+", "+", "+", "G1^{S342G}", "G1^{S342G}", "+", 
"+", "G1^{S342G}", "G1^{S342G}", "Blank", "Blank", "+", "+", 
"+", "+", "+", "+", "G1^{S342G}", "G1^{S342G}", "+", "+", "Blank", 
"Blank", "+", "+", "G1^{S342G}", "G1^{S342G}", "G1^{S342G}", 
"G1^{S342G}", "G1^{S342G}", "G1^{S342G}", "G1^{S342G}", "G1^{S342G}", 
"Blank", "Blank", "+", "+", "G1^{S342G}", "G1^{S342G}", "G1^{S342G}", 
"G1^{S342G}", "+", "+", "G1^{S342G}", "G1^{S342G}", "G1^{S342G}", 
"G1^{S342G}", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "G1^{S342G}", "G1^{S342G}", 
"+", "+", "G1^{S342G}", "G1^{S342G}", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", 
"+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "G1^{S342G}", "G1^{S342G}", 
"G1^{S342G}", "G1^{S342G}", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "G1^{S342G}", 
"G1^{S342G}", "G1^{S342G}", "G1^{S342G}", "+", "+", "+", "+", 
"+", "+", "G1^{S342G}", "G1^{S342G}"), G1_1_2 = c("Blank", "Blank", 
"+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "Blank", "Blank", 
"+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "Blank", "Blank", 
"+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "Blank", "Blank", 
"+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", 
"+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "G1^{S342G}", "G1^{S342G}", "+", "+", 
"+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", 
"+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "G1^{S342G}", 
"G1^{S342G}", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+"
), G1_2_1 = c("Blank", "Blank", "+", "+", "+", "+", "G1^{I384M}", 
"G1^{I384M}", "+", "+", "G1^{I384M}", "G1^{I384M}", "Blank", 
"Blank", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "G1^{I384M}", "G1^{I384M}", 
"+", "+", "Blank", "Blank", "+", "+", "G1^{I384M}", "G1^{I384M}", 
"G1^{I384M}", "G1^{I384M}", "G1^{I384M}", "G1^{I384M}", "G1^{I384M}", 
"G1^{I384M}", "Blank", "Blank", "+", "+", "G1^{I384M}", "G1^{I384M}", 
"G1^{I384M}", "G1^{I384M}", "+", "+", "G1^{I384M}", "G1^{I384M}", 
"G1^{I384M}", "G1^{I384M}", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "G1^{I384M}", 
"G1^{I384M}", "+", "+", "G1^{I384M}", "G1^{I384M}", "+", "+", 
"Blank", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "G1^{I384M}", 
"G1^{I384M}", "G1^{I384M}", "G1^{I384M}", "+", "+", "+", "+", 
"+", "+", "G1^{I384M}", "G1^{I384M}", "G1^{I384M}", "G1^{I384M}", 
"+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "G1^{I384M}", "G1^{I384M}"), G1_2_2 = c("Blank", 
"Blank", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "Blank", 
"Blank", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "Blank", 
"Blank", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "Blank", 
"Blank", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", 
"+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "G1^{I384M}", "G1^{I384M}", 
"+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "Blank", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", 
"+", "+", "+", "+", "G1^{I384M}", "G1^{I384M}", "+", "+", "+", 
"+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "G1^{I384M}", "G1^{I384M}", "+", "+", 
"+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+"), G2_1 = c("Blank", "Blank", 
"+", "+", "+", "+", "G2", "G2", "+", "+", "G2", "G2", "Blank", 
"Blank", "+", "+", "G2", "G2", "G2", "G2", "+", "+", "+", "+", 
"Blank", "Blank", "G2", "G2", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", 
"+", "Blank", "Blank", "G2", "G2", "G2", "G2", "+", "+", "+", 
"+", "+", "+", "G2", "G2", "G2", "G2", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", 
"+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "G2", "G2", "G2", 
"G2", "G2", "G2", "G2", "G2", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", 
"+", "G2", "G2", "+", "+", "+", "+", "G2", "G2", "+", "+", "+", 
"+", "+", "+"), G2_2 = c("Blank", "Blank", "+", "+", "+", "+", 
"+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "Blank", "Blank", "+", "+", "+", 
"+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "Blank", "Blank", "+", "+", 
"+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "Blank", "Blank", "+", 
"+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", 
"+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", 
"+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", 
"+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", 
"+", "+", "+", "+", "+"), `Final genotype of APOL1` = c("NA", 
"NA", "G0/G0", "G0/G0", "G0/G0", "G0/G0", "G1^{GM}/G2", "G1^{GM}/G2", 
"G0/G0", "G0/G0", "G1^{GM}/G2", "G1^{GM}/G2", "NA", "NA", "G0/G0", 
"G0/G0", "G0/G2", "G0/G2", "G0/G2", "G0/G2", "G1^{GM}/G0", "G1^{GM}/G0", 
"G0/G0", "G0/G0", "NA", "NA", "G0/G2", "G0/G2", "G1^{GM}/G0", 
"G1^{GM}/G0", "G1^{GM}/G0", "G1^{GM}/G0", "G1^{GM}/G0", "G1^{GM}/G0", 
"G1^{GM}/G0", "G1^{GM}/G0", "NA", "NA", "G0/G2", "G0/G2", "G1^{GM}/G2", 
"G1^{GM}/G2", "G1^{GM}/G0", "G1^{GM}/G0", "G0/G0", "G0/G0", "G1^{GM}/G0", 
"G1^{GM}/G0", "G1^{GM}/G2", "G1^{GM}/G2", "G0/G2", "G0/G2", "G0/G0", 
"G0/G0", "G0/G0", "G0/G0", "G1^{GM}/G1^{GM}", "G1^{GM}/G1^{GM}", 
"G0/G0", "G0/G0", "G1^{GM}/G0", "G1^{GM}/G0", "G0/G0", "G0/G0", 
NA, "G0/G0", "G0/G2", "G0/G2", "G0/G2", "G0/G2", "G0/G2", "G0/G2", 
"G0/G2", "G0/G2", "G1^{GM}/G0", "G1^{GM}/G0", "G1^{GM}/G0", "G1^{GM}/G0", 
"G0/G0", "G0/G0", "G0/G0", "G0/G0", "G0/G2", "G0/G2", "G1^{GM}/G1^{GM}", 
"G1^{GM}/G1^{GM}", "G1^{GM}/G0", "G1^{GM}/G0", "G0/G2", "G0/G2", 
"G0/G0", "G0/G0", "G0/G0", "G0/G0", "G1^{GM}/G0", "G1^{GM}/G0"
), `no APOL1 Risk Alleles` = c(NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, 1, 
1, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, 1, 
1, NA, NA, 1, 1, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, 
1, NA, NA), `1 APOL1 Risk Alleles` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, 1, 1, NA, NA, 
1, 1, NA, NA, 1, 1, NA, NA, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 
1), `2 APOL1 Risk Alleles` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 
NA, NA, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
1, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 
1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Sample_Flag = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)), row.names = c(NA, -96L), class = "data.frame")
```

dataframe (Validation_controls)

```
"F01", "F02", "G01", "G02", "H01", "H02"), class = "factor"), 
    Final.genotype.of.APOL1 = structure(c(4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("G0/G2", "G1^{GM}/G0", "G1^{GM}/G1^{GM}", 
    "G1^{GM}/G2"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Comment: @akrun please could you help me with this problem also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Final <- Final %>% mutate(`Control_Validation` = case_when(
      `Well` %in% c("E01", "E02") & (`Final genotype of APOL1` == "G1^{GM}/G2") ~ "Match",
      `Well` %in% c("F01", "F02") & (`Final genotype of APOL1` == "G1^{GM}/G0") ~ "Match",
      `Well` %in% c("G01", "G02") & (`Final genotype of APOL1` == "G0/G2") ~ "Match",     
      `Well` %in% c("H01", "H02") & (`Final genotype of APOL1` == "G1^{GM}/G1^{GM}") ~ "Match"))
```